# TeX Live personal texmf tree

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, texmf

I have installed **Tex Live 2012** in both **Windows 7** (`C:\texlive`) and **Ubuntu 12.04** (`/usr/local/texlive`). Inside both these folders there are two folders namely `2012` and `texmf-local`. My question is that if I want to install a package manually for example the acmsmall package for a particular ACM journal, where do I put the `.cls` and `.bst` files. Please note I want to user install the package. Is the folder named `texmf-local` my personal texmf tree or do I need to create a separate texmf tree?

Comment: It is not difficult to find the duplicates for this question.

Comment: point me to one

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/19356

Answer (score 1):

put it into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/acmsmall`. For MikTeX you can create also a local texmf tree with the setup manager. After saving the files run `texhash` or update the file name database (MikTeX)

Comment: then wats the use of ~/texmf?

Comment: that is `$TEXMFHOME` which can be used by a local user and do not need a `texhash`; it is searched recursively.